# Setting the column fields for a laravel model

Tags: php, laravel

In another mvc framework like django,we can define the column fields by defining the attributes in the corresponding model clas.

How to do that in laravel?

```
class Model {
              name : string;
              address:string;
    }
```

In the model class we can declare the column for the database and its data type ?

How to do that in laravel?

Comment: we do this in the migration file https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations

Comment: See also: Eloquent casting; https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at the [official Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent) (eloquent section, ORM) if you use Laravel. You don't define that in your Model, but in a migration, that is creating a table for your Model data.

For migrations, see [Laravel Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations)